# Set vite env-varible value in the pnpm script

Tags: environment-variables, vite, pnpm

I tried to set varible right in to the pnpm script:

`"build": BUILD_PLATFORM=web vite build`

But getting an error:

`'BUILD_PLATFORM' is not recognized as an internal or external command`
operable program or batch file

I need to set value for environment variable in script call

`.env` file approach seems to be incorrect, because every time I want to call one of my scripts, I should change varible value in `.env` file accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution in pre-launching module that modifies the `.env` file before executing current script

In my case it looks like this:

```
"build:desktop": "tsx prebuild-setup/desktop.ts && vite build",
"build:web": "tsx prebuild-setup/web.ts && vite build",
```

`desktop.ts` & `web.ts` are executing before `vite build` and make changes to `.env` file, so at build time, code will use proper variable values, no need to change `.env` file manualy every time before calling scripts

note: tsx - package for running TypeScript